# CSS style to implement curved circle

Tags: html, css, user-interface, bootstrap-4

I just want to implement the header part like the attachment. Can someone help me to do this using CSS.

[image]

Comment: if your familiar with svg you can also do it without css and show some code

Answer (score 0):

**Note: You can do it by using 2 divs with `absolute positioning` with their parent as `relative positioned`**

**Working code:**

```css
.c-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.red {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 200px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.red-1 {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="c-wrapper">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="red-1"></div>
</div>
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sq6zyf89/1/)